# How to play audio from rtmp stream in javacv?

Tags: java, audio, rtmp, javacv

I am trying to play rtmp stream using javav library, I can play the video part without problems but when I want to play the audio part I can not figure out what to do exactly and I use FFmpegFrameGrabber class in javacv to get the video.

```
FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FmpegFrameGrabber("rtmp://184.72.239.149/vod/BigBuckBunny_115k.mov");
grabber.setFormat("flv");
grabber.start();
CanvasFrame cFrame = new CanvasFrame("Capture Preview2222", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma() / grabber.getGamma());
cFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

while( ( capturedFrame = grabber.grab() )  != null)
{
   if( cFrame.isVisible() )
   {
      cFrame.showImage( capturedFrame );

    }
}
```